# Primary Key Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, primary-key, create-table

Other than visually, is there a functional difference between declaring the primary in the column definition or down at the bottom?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    content TEXT
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is the above different than:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    content TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: No. I like `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, because it involves less typing

Comment: Is SERIAL PRIMARY KEY the same as NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`. If you use the former, then SHOW CREATE TABLE and you'll see it is rewritten as the latter.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Don't need a BIGINT so I'll just use the longhand id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both syntaxes are equivalent.

The first one uses a *column* constraint.

The second syntax uses *table* constraint, and is mostly useful when you want a *compound* primary key, that references more than one column (in which case it is not possible to use a column constraint).

Comment: Just as addition, the same logic applies for *compound checks* (i.e. checks that compare values from multiple columns).